# How to fetch data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table customers
    (
    custID int(11) primary key, 
    customerName varchar(50),
    phone varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    state varchar(50),
    postalCode varchar(15),
    country varchar(50),
    creditLimit Decimal(10,2)
    );

create table product
(
    productID varchar(15) primary key,
    productName varchar(70),
    productVendor varchar(50),
    productDescription text,
    qtyInStock smallint(6),
    price Decimal(10,2)
);

create table orders
(
    orderNumber int(11) primary key,
    orderDate date,
    requiredDate date,
    shippedDate date,
    status varchar(15),
    comments text,
    custID int(11),
    salesID int(11),
    foreign key(custID) references customers(custID),
    foreign key(salesID) references salespersonnel(employeeID)
);
```

here are three tables, i want to fetch  all of the orders of one particular customer and their total money spent.

I have two entries in order table and payment table

Payment Table:
[image]

Order table:
[image]

I am executing this query

```
select count(p.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders', sum(amount) as 'Amount Spent'
from orders p,
     payments q
where p.custid = q.custid
  and q.custid = 1;
```

This query is generating double result 
that means total of 2200 must be returned as the total amount spent, but i am getting 4400 
and total 2 orders are placed by customer, but i am getting 4. Please help

Comment: I think a simple `GROUP BY` should help you

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: How to use join on this table, can you help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the 2 tables on the `ordernumber` column:

```
select 
  count(o.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders', 
  sum(p.amount) as 'Amount Spent'
from orders o inner join payment p
on p.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
where o.custid = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NT4bY2GkeY9gNR152HGVr/0)
If you want to get these sums for every customer:

```
select
  o.custid,
  count(o.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders', 
  sum(p.amount) as 'Amount Spent'
from orders o inner join payment p
on p.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
group by o.custid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate *before* joining.  Otherwise, you will get a Cartesian product (and the wrong results as you see):

```
select o.custid, o.Total_Orders, p.Amount_Spent
from (select o.cust_id, count(*) as total_orders
      from orders o
      group by o.custid
     ) o left join 
     (select p.cust_id, sum(amount) as amount_spent
      from payments p
      group by p.cust_id
     ) p
     on p.custid = o.custid ;
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to filter the results.  You can do it in the outer query or in the subqueries.  The latter is better from a performance perspective.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use *meaningful* table aliases.  `p` for `orders` instead of `payments` is just confusing.
- Only use letters, digits, and underscore in column aliases, so they do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Error in syntax :(